# Issues installing encrypted lubuntu 17.04 64bit

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu, encryption

Ok so i'm trying to install lubuntu 17.04 from disc, im on the test linux option withought installing atm.

I am now trying to run an encrypted install, but i ran into some issues:

An unsafe swap space has been detected... so I opened Terminal and use sudo swapoff --all and restarted the installation.

That was fixed but then i ran into a new error: Unexpected error while creating volume group: Autopartitioning using LVM failed because an error occurred while creating the volume group. Check /var/log/syslog or see virtual console 4 for the details.

To fix this, I did sudo apt-get install lvm2 and restarted the installation.

Then that was fixed but ran into another new issue,saying: Configuration of encrypted volumes failed: An error occurred while configuring encrypted volumes. The configuration has been aborted.

what do i do to fix this? I saw someone with the exact same problem on here but there was no solution.

Any help please?

Comment: does no one know? the only thing i havent tried is downloading an older version of lubuntu and trying to see if that works. which i'd rather not do unless i have to

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and initially attempted to resolve it by taking exactly the same steps as the original poster.

In my case, I was trying to install Lubuntu to an encrypted HDD with Linux Mint previously installed. The solution: once I unmounted the HDD, I was able to proceed with no problems.

Unmounting the HDD was simply a matter of double-clicking the "Trash" icon on the desktop, locating the HDD on the left-hand panel, right-clicking it, and selecting "Unmount".